# Tinymce sink element decreases page loading time

Tags: php, foreach, tinymce, textarea, page-load-time

For a blog file, all the comments on the articles, created by a php foreach loop, have each their own `Reply` button what opens a modal dialog with tinymce in the textarea. 
A noticed, when there are may comments, the page loading takes some time. When i looked in the brower-inspector, i see at the end tiny is loading for each textarea a "sink" element just before the close tag of the `body`:

```
<div class="tox tox-silver-sink tox-tinymce-aux" style="position: relative;"></div>
<div class="tox tox-silver-sink tox-tinymce-aux" style="position: relative;"></div>
<div class="tox tox-silver-sink tox-tinymce-aux" style="position: relative;"></div>
<div class="tox tox-silver-sink tox-tinymce-aux" style="position: relative;"></div>
<div class="tox tox-silver-sink tox-tinymce-aux" style="position: relative;"></div>
....and so on...
```

The loading of these divs takes some time and it decreases the performance of the page loading.
Is there anything i can do about this to increase the performance of page loading?

Comment: same problem you found decision?

Comment: Obviously you only need one reply modal. It will be difficult to answer this question because it is totally unclear how your reply modal works, that code is missing from the question.

Comment: how you solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As KIKO said, you need to have a single reply modal for all comments. Since you didn't specify what platform you're using, here's a general approach.

Each reply button should have a data attribute with the ID of the comment you want to reply to. For example

```
<button class="reply-button" data-comment-id="<?php echo $comment->id; ?>">Reply</button>
```

Or leave the `data-comment-id` attribute empty if the comment is going to be attached to the post, and not as a reply to some other comment.

If you're showing multiple blog posts on a single page and want each to have their own reply button, just add data attribute `post-id`, like so:

```
<button class="reply-button" data-post-id="<?php echo $blog_post->id; ?>">Reply</button>
```

Use JavaScript to open comment modal and pick up the appropriate data attribute. For example:

```
$('.reply-button').on('click', function() {
    const commentId = $(this).data('comment-id');
    const postId = $(this).data('post-id');
    showCommentModal(commentId, postId);
});
```

`showCommentModal` function should show the single modal you have on the page. Using `commentId` and `postId` it should prepare to post the comment either as a reply to another comment or to a blog post.